# 'Branch is up to date' despite code being different in local repository compared to remote repository after rebasing

Tags: git, github

Despite several .cs files being different in my local repository compared to my remote one, a 'git status' throws a 'nothing to commit, working tree clean'.

This particularly happened after rebasing due to some minor merge conflicts. I can check my .cs files and see they're different in my remote repository compared to local one, but yet I am not able to stage, commit and push anything.

Can I force my local main to override the remote main and will it delete previous commits?

EDIT: Added picture of the log - top commit is only local and can't be pushed or seen remotely although saying working tree is clean
[image]

Comment: If your working tree is clean that means that you haven’t made any changes relative to your current commit. The remote doesn’t matter.

Comment: "nothing to _commit_" means you have no uncommitted local changes. That's unrelated to having commits not _pushed_ to a remote repository.

Comment: @Guildenstern But I have - I can even open the .cs files and see they're different from in GitHub

Comment: Read `man git status`.

Comment: @Guildenstern 'git status' yields branch is up to date and working tree is clean despite the local .cs files not being updated remotely. I only have one main branch pushing in to so it can't be due to being on a different branch

Comment: What do you expect `git status` to do?

Comment: Your origin does seem up to date with your local. 1. Are you sure there are differences? 2. Are you really sure you are looking at the correct "origin" when you see differences? Check `git remote -v` and follow the link. And yes, every commit id comes with its history, and these will fully "replace" the previous branch content.

Comment: @bebbi Yes - there are most definitely differences as I have fixed some code. 'git remote -v' leads back to 'main' in the repo last being updated by commit 'ef33...' as seen in the above picture I have included.

I can usually fix mistakes like these as they seem quite simple but this is perplexing me. Despite '983d...' not being pushed remotely it shows as working tree being clean

Comment: I think there is some problem going on with GitHub right now. I am also having similar issue since last 3 hrs. I asked this question just now: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76210377/3368518

Comment: @SourabhBhat Thanks for tuning in - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what's going on but if you changed your local history (rebase), then you can't simply push anymore.

To force overwrite the remote:

```bash
git push -f
```

To discard local changes and force local main to be the same as origin:

```bash
git fetch
git checkout main
git reset --hard origin/main
```

Comment: 'git fetch' yields nothing as my working tree is clean despite having different .cs files. Checking out yields nothing since I am only on the branch.

Resetting main with the last command simply yields the HEAD being moved along with my latest commit message - interestingly, this commit does not show up on GitHub, which was last updated earlier. So despite my local commit message being different when resetting than the one in my remote repo, it doesn't seem to detect any changes and therefore I can't push

Comment: Your screenshot confirms that your local main is identical with your remote origin/main. Also, commit message is encoded in commit id, so if commit ids are same, the commit message must be the same.

Comment: The remote as seen/browsed on GitHub could be different from `origin/main` if `git fetch` hasn’t been run recently. But you have run `git fetch` so it should be the same.

Comment: @Guildenstern fetching doesn't change anything despite the .cs files still being different. It doesn't even "revert" the .cs files and I am still left with the ones I changed being different from the ones pushed two hours ago