# GitHub website does not show files, but the files are present when I clone the repository

Tags: git, github

I pushed some changes to my public repository:
https://github.com/heySourabh/Triangulate

I am not able to see the latest commit on **GitHub website**. I can see latest changes if I clone the repository, using
`git clone https://github.com/heySourabh/Triangulate.git`. For eg. I can see `src/node_search.py` when I clone it, which is not visible on the GitHub.

I am puzzled by this! The new files are present in the repository, but not visible on GitHub website?

My first thought was that GitHub website is taking some time to update. But now it has been more than 3 hrs, since I pushed the changes but they are still not updated on the website!

Any comments or insights are welcome. Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

Was fixed automatically... 1 commit and 4 hours later. :)

Comment: This might be a side-effect of an ongoing/currently-ending [problem at GitHub](https://www.githubstatus.com/). Or it might be something entirely different. Did you try editing an URL like this: https://github.com/heySourabh/Triangulate/commit/f3b61d81deb2bfadc7c9551ee63fac3bf060ce4a to include the hash of your latest commit?

Comment: I was curious and cloned the repo and can confirm: there's an "invisible commit". Github has it, as seen at https://github.com/heySourabh/Triangulate/commit/26f84dd8c66fc079844aab8a9985e97b8a373b02. I suspect this is a side-effect of the earlier snafu at github. I wouldn't worry aobut it, it'll probably solve itself.